# How to run java files from different packages in command prompt?

Tags: java, command

I need to run a java program in Windows using the command prompt. JAVAC is running perfectly in my computer. However, when I tried to compile my code (javac sampleprog.java), it displayed an error saying that it can't find the imported packages and classes I used in the program. What command should I use? Or how could I solve this? My java programs are stored in different packages and this sampleprog.java uses an API and calls different methods from different classes.

Thanks!

Comment: `javac sampleprog.java` doesn't run your program, it compiles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the directory that contains the compiled class files e.g. `c:\myproj\classes`

Then invoke `java com.myproject.MyClass` where `com.myproject.MyClass` is the fully qualified path to MyClass.

If you have dependencies on third party libraries you may also need to add the `-classpath` flag e.g.  `java -classpath c:\path\to\some\lib.jar com.myproject.MyClass`

Comment: What if my java prog needs to call a method from other package? Will -classpath work as well?

Comment: If the other package is contained within your classes directory or the package is contain in a lib already on your classpath, then no. However, suppose you have a jar file that contains a class you would like to reference. If that jar is not on your classpath, you will not be able to use it. In such a case, you can add it to your classpath

Comment: My program is divided into different packages. Let's say I stored my database in /src/Entities and my modules in /src/Module... My MainClass that is found in Modules needs the method in Entities. Should I type in the command? java -classpath C:\path\to\package MainClass?

Answer (score 0):

After you compile it with `javac`, you can run it with `java YourFile`

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was what I meant :)) Compile.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to run it with  `java YourFile.class`. You would run it with `java YourFile`. You don't include `.class` when using the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

Go to root of your class files. For example `c:/proj/classes`. If your class name is `MyClass` and it belongs to package `com.mycompany` you should find file `com/mycompany/MyClass.class` there.

If so type in command prompt `java com.mycompany.MyClass` and press ENTER.

Pay attention that when you are using `javac` you have to type the extension `*.java`, however when you are running the class you have not type extension `.class`. The string `com.mycompany.MyClass` is called *fully qualified class name*. This name is used by JVM to load class.